# Value becomes empty in sql command?

Tags: mysql

busy for several hours now, to find out what i am doing wrong.

In an update sql value becomes empty??

```
if(ctype_digit($_POST['id'])
    AND
    $_SESSION['captain'] == 1
    AND
    $_SESSION['team'] == $_POST['id'])

{
    $teamtekst = $_POST['value'];

    // update text
    $q = "UPDATE teams
                SET
                    teamtekst = '".mysql_real_escape_string($teamtekst)."' 
                WHERE
                    team_id = '".$_POST['id']."'
                LIMIT 1";
    $exec = mysql_query($q);
    if(mysql_affected_rows($exec) == 1)
        echo'ok';
    else
        echo $q.' '.$_POST['value'];


}
    else
    {
    echo 'Fout in gegevens? Tekst niet opgeslagen!'; // faultmessage
    }
```

It echo's: UPDATE teams SET teamtekst = ''  WHERE team_id = '29' LIMIT 1 test
so test is the real value of $_POST['value'] but does not show up in sql statement?

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not an sql error , `$_POST['value']` is not set
use `var_dump($_POST)` to know what's inside the $_POST array and check if the `$_POST['value']` is already set before

Comment: ayman, thanks for your answer, but the value is already checked with echo $q.' '.$_POST['value']; and there it does show a value. i really am desperade now:(

Comment: @Terradon if it is printed then the problem is with mysql_real_escape_string , a mysql connection must be established before using this function

Comment: Sh**, did i really have forgotten my db connection?? Unbelievable, but yes i did:(